# Developer key required for this operation

Tags: php, youtube-api

I dont find the solution for my "Developer key required for this operation" problem.

here is my code:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php'; // the Zend dir must be in your include_path
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();

Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin'); 


$authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
$httpClient = 
  Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
              $username = '************@gmail.com',
              $password = '************',
              $service = 'youtube',
              $client = null,
              $source = '************', // a short string identifying your application
              $loginToken = null,
              $loginCaptcha = null,
              $authenticationURL);

// Note that this example creates an unversioned service object.
// You do not need to specify a version number to upload content
// since the upload behavior is the same for all API versions.
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient);

// create a new VideoEntry object
$myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

// create a new Zend_Gdata_App_MediaFileSource object
$filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource('asd.avi');
$filesource->setContentType('video/x-ms-wmv');
// set slug header
$filesource->setSlug('asd.avi');

// add the filesource to the video entry
$myVideoEntry->setMediaSource($filesource);

$myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('My Test Movie');
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('My Test Movie');
// The category must be a valid YouTube category!
$myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Autos');

// Set keywords. Please note that this must be a comma-separated string
// and that individual keywords cannot contain whitespace
$myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('cars, funny');

// set some developer tags -- this is optional
// (see Searching by Developer Tags for more details)
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDeveloperTags(array('mydevtag', 'anotherdevtag'));

// set the video's location -- this is also optional
$yt->registerPackage('Zend_Gdata_Geo');
$yt->registerPackage('Zend_Gdata_Geo_Extension');
$where = $yt->newGeoRssWhere();
$position = $yt->newGmlPos('37.0 -122.0');
$where->point = $yt->newGmlPoint($position);
$myVideoEntry->setWhere($where);

// upload URI for the currently authenticated user
$uploadUrl = 'http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads';

// try to upload the video, catching a Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException, 
// if available, or just a regular Zend_Gdata_App_Exception otherwise
try {
  $newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) {
  echo $httpException->getRawResponseBody();
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

i try to use my devkey with the following lines, but where i need to put this?

```
$developerKey = 'ABC123 ... ';
$applicationId = 'Video uploader v1';
$clientId = 'My video upload client - v1';

$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);
```

i try to find a fully working PHP code to upload video to youtube, but dont find anything........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient);
```

you need to do the following:

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);
```

Note that $applicationId and $clientId must each be valid ids. Unless already available, you can create your application and client ids here: https://code.google.com/apis/console/

You can obtain your developer key by registering here: https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/index.html#settings

Comment: Thanks for helping, Working!

Answer (score 2):

#### **How to get Developer Key**

The developer key can be obtained by creating a product in Google YouTube API.

Login to your [Google Account](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=youtubepartnersyn&passive=true&nui=1&continue=https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/&followup=https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/):

[image: step 1]

It will automatically redirect you to the create developer profile if it's your first time:

[image: step 2]

After creating your developer profile, go ahead and create a product, it could be everything you want.

[image: step3]

After creating your product you will get the developer key in the censored textbox ("Developer key here")

[image: step4]

Copy that to your code, and if you are using version 3 of the API you can get a client key down there.

#### **How to get Client ID**

In order to get a client id you need to create an API project in Google API's console.

[Google API's Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

After logging in you will see this page! Press create project and create your project:

[image: 2step1]

It will automatically create project for you, and now on you need to select the services you want to use. If you are going to use YouTube, select YouTube Data API.

[image: 2step2]

Now you will be able to go the API Access tab. Create an OAuth ID there.

[image: 2step3]

Enter your product info:

[image: 2step4]

Choose its type:

[image: 2step5]

Get your client id! :D

[image: 2step6]

Comment: yes i know this, but i dont know the clientID -> https://code.google.com/apis/console/