# Youtube-API upload script moving to HostGator

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api, gdata

My youtube upload script is working great. *([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773392/developer-key-required-for-this-operation))*

Now i want to move my uploader script to HOSTGATOR.
But when i want to run my working script;

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException' with
>   message 'Authentication with Google failed. Reason: BadAuthentication'
>   in
>   /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxx.eu/upload/Zend/Gdata/ClientLogin.php:175
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxx.eu/upload/index.php(47):
>   Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient('jozsefsandor45@...',
>   'mynicepass', 'youtube', NULL, 'thisisasecret', NULL, NULL,
>   'https://www.goo...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxx.eu/upload/Zend/Gdata/ClientLogin.php
>   on line 175

Is anybody can help me?
I say again, this was a working scipt.
If i change my password to a BAD password the error message is same!
Now i think my login information is not reach the google servers...

Comment: did you read the error message? "BadAuthentication" seems obvious enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haha this was funny, when i try to investigate the problem i log into my youtube account and i read the following text;

> Suspicious activity in your account
>   We detected activity on your Google Account from a location you don't usually sign in from. Review the information below and tell us whether you recognize this activity.

So thats it :)
Check your profile if you get the following error with a working script.